# Tooltips are being hidden behind timeline points

Tags: css, vis.js

I have vis.js timeline setup and I am using point items on my timeline with custom tooltips.  The tooltips are being hidden being the items on the timeline.  The odd thing is that the tooltips behave as expected for the first 6-7 points on the timeline and then they start to go behind the timeline point items.

```
body {
font: 10pt arial;
}
.timeline-bg {
background-image: url(assets/images/time-bg.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
}
.timeline-header {
    background: #044c60;
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.zoom-nav {
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.zoom-nav-left {
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#moveLeft,#moveRight {
    font-size:16px;
}
.vis-january, .vis-february, .vis-march, .vis-april, .vis-may, .vis-june, .vis-july, .vis-august, .vis-september, .vis-october, .vis-november, .vis-december {
font-weight: 700;
color: #044c60 !important;
}
.container {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;

}
.container-today {
  width: 17px;
  text-align: center;
}
.milestone {
  border:6px solid #d9d9d9 !important;
  border-radius:50%;
  color:#044c60 !important;
  background: #fff !important;
  margin: 30px 0 0 -10px !important;
}
.milestone .fas {
    font-size:25px;
}
.milestone-past {
  border:6px solid #05a0a0 !important;
  border-radius:50%;
  color:#05a0a0 !important;
  background: #fff !important;
  margin: 30px 0 0 -10px !important;
}
.milestone-past .fas {
    font-size:25px;
}
.milestone-past-check {
    position: absolute;
    top:-18px;
    left:-12px;
    z-index: 10;
    color: #fff;
    background: #05a0a0;

    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 15px;
}
.milestone-past-check .fas {
    font-size:12px;
}
.milestone-started {
    position: absolute;
    top:-18px;
    left:-12px;
    z-index: 10;
    color: #fff;
    background: #044c60;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 15px;
}
.milestone-started .fas {
    font-size:12px;
}
.today {
  border:6px solid #044c60 !important;
  background: #fff !important;
  color: #044c60 !important;
  border-radius:50%;      
  margin: 35px 0 0 -3px !important;
}
.task {
  color:#044c60 !important;
  margin: 42px 0 0 6px !important;
}
.task-past {
  color:#fff !important;
  margin: 42px 0 0 4px !important;
}
.vis-item.vis-dot {
  display: none;
}
.vis-background {

}
.vis-item.vis-background {
  height: 20px !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 54.5px !important;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
}
.vis-item.vis-background.blue {
  background-color: #05a0a0 !important;
}
.vis-time-axis .vis-grid.vis-vertical {
    border:0 !important;
}
.vis-time-axis .vis-text {
    margin-left: -3px;
}

/* Tooltip container */
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10000;
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px; 
  /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:100%;
  transform:translate(0, -50%);
  margin-left:20px;
  z-index: 10000;
  /*margin-top: 8px;*/
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top:50%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  /*margin-left: -10px;*/
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
  z-index: 10000;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Timeline | Background areas</title>

  <script src="assets/javascripts/visjs/vis.js"></script>
  <link href="assets/stylesheets/visjs/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

<div id="timeline-wrapper">
    <div class="timeline-header"><div class="zoom-nav-left"><span id="moveLeft"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> Previous</span></div>Timeline<div class="zoom-nav"><span id="moveRight">Next <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span> <span id="zoomIn"><i class="fas fa-search-plus"></i></span> <span id="zoomOut"><i class="fas fa-search-minus"></i></span></div></div>
    <div id="visualization" class="timeline-bg"></div>
</div>
<script>

  var items = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 'A', content: '', start: '2019-01-01', end: '2019-12-31', type: 'background', className: 'gray'},
    {id: 'B', content: '', start: '2019-01-01', end: '2019-04-17', type: 'background', className: 'blue'},
    {id: 1, content: '<div class="tooltip"><i class="fas fa-check"></i><span class="tooltiptext">Complete<br>Task 1 - 3 April 2019</span></div>', start: '2019-04-03', className: 'task-past', type: 'point'},
    {id: 2, content: '<div class="tooltip"><i class="fas fa-check"></i><span class="tooltiptext">Complete<br>Task 2 - 9 April 2019</span></div>', start: '2019-04-09', className: 'task-past', type: 'point'},
    {id: 3, content: '<div class="container tooltip"><span class="milestone-past-check"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span><i class="fas fa-atlas"></i><span class="tooltiptext">Complete<br>Visa Renewal - 14 April 2019</span></div>', start: '2019-04-14', className: 'milestone-past', type: 'point'},
    {id: 4, content: '<div class="container-today tooltip"><i class="fas fa-male"></i><span class="tooltiptext">Today</span></div>', start: '2019-04-17', className: 'today', type: 'point'},
    {id: 5, content: '<div class="tooltip"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i><span class="tooltiptext">My Text</span></div>', start: '2019-04-19', className: 'task', type:'point'},
    {id: 6, content: '<div class="tooltip"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i><span class="tooltiptext">My Text</span></div>', start: '2019-05-01', className: 'task', type:'point'},
    {id: 7, content: '<div class="tooltip"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i><span class="tooltiptext">My Text<br>test<br>test</span></div>', start: '2019-05-09', className: 'task', type:'point'},
    {id: 8, content: '<div class="container tooltip"><span class="milestone-started"><i class="fas fa-spinner"></i></span><i class="fas fa-sign"></i><span class="tooltiptext">My Text</span></div>', start: '2019-05-16', className: 'milestone', type:'point'},
    {id: 9, content: '<div class="tooltip"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i><span class="tooltiptext">My Text</span></div>', start: '2019-05-26', className: 'task', type:'point'},
    {id: 10, content: '<div class="tooltip"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i><span class="tooltiptext">My Text</span></div>', start: '2019-06-06', className: 'task', type:'point'},
    {id: 11, content: '<div class="container tooltip"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><span class="tooltiptext">My Text</span></div>', start: '2019-06-11', className: 'milestone', type:'point'},
    {id: 12, content: '<div class="tooltip"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i><span class="tooltiptext">My Text</span></div>', start: '2019-06-16', className: 'task', type:'point'},
    {id: 13, content: '<div class="tooltip"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i><span class="tooltiptext">My Text</span></div>', start: '2019-06-21', className: 'task', type:'point'},
    {id: 14, content: '<div class="container tooltip"><i class="fas fa-home"></i><span class="tooltiptext">My Text</span></div>', start: '2019-06-21', className: 'milestone', type:'point'}
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
  var options = {

    editable: false,
    orientation: 'top',
    height: '180px',
    showCurrentTime: false,
    stack: false,
    zoomMin: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31,
    /*zoomMin: 604800000,*/
    start: '2019-04-01',
    end: '2019-06-30',
    moveable: true,
    zoomable: true,
    showTooltips: false,
    min: '2019-01-01',
    max: '2019-12-31'

  };

  var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container);
  timeline.setOptions(options);
  timeline.setItems(items);

  /**
 * Move the timeline a given percentage to left or right
 * @param {Number} percentage   For example 0.1 (left) or -0.1 (right)
 */
function move (percentage) {
    var range = timeline.getWindow();
    var interval = range.end - range.start;

    timeline.setWindow({
        start: range.start.valueOf() - interval * percentage,
        end:   range.end.valueOf()   - interval * percentage
    });
}

/**
 * Zoom the timeline a given percentage in or out
 * @param {Number} percentage   For example 0.1 (zoom out) or -0.1 (zoom in)
 */
function zoom (percentage) {
    var range = timeline.getWindow();
    var interval = range.end - range.start;

    timeline.setWindow({
        start: range.start.valueOf() - interval * percentage,
        end:   range.end.valueOf()   + interval * percentage
    });
}

// attach events to the navigation buttons
document.getElementById('zoomIn').onclick    = function () { zoom(-0.2); };
document.getElementById('zoomOut').onclick   = function () { zoom( 0.2); };
document.getElementById('moveLeft').onclick  = function () { move( 0.7); };
document.getElementById('moveRight').onclick = function () { move(-0.7); };
//document.getElementById('fit').onclick       = function () { timeline.fit(); };

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/smwelch/oqwvyaL9/2/

I have tried everything I can think of including z-index.  The weird thing is that the tooltips on the first 6 points on the timeline work as expected and then they start going being the points further down the timeline

https://jsfiddle.net/smwelch/oqwvyaL9/2/

I need the tooltips to be on top of the timeline points

Answer (score 0):

It's because your html is being rendered wrong. In:

```
<div class="vis-foreground">
   <div class="vis-group">
      <div class="vis-item vis-point task vis-readonly">...
```

the first 7 vis-item divs start from the middle and go the front and then there is a 2nd set of vis-item divs that are rendered so those overlap the first set. All you have to do is cut and paste every div set after the 7th div to the top of the vis-group. I added the cut and pasted effort in a jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/sqz81oe9/

Comment: The html is being rendered by javascript.  I am using vis.js, visjs.org.  The html is rendered by date on a timeline.